# How to PUT S3 objects from another AWS account into your own account S3 bucket using assume role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, copy, bucket

I have a pretty typical use case where I have a role granted to me in AWS account (1234567890 - not under my control) to read data from their S3 bucket ('remote_bucket'). I can read the data from remote bucket just fine, but I no longer can dump it into my own bucket, because assuming role in another AWS account "hides" grants to resource on my own account. Last row fails with the error. How to solve this?

```
import boto3

# Create IAM client and local session
sts = boto3.client('sts')
local_sess = boto3.Session()
s3_local = local_sess.resource('s3')

role_to_assume_arn='arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/s3_role'
role_session_name='test'

# Assume role in another account to access their S3 bucket
response = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn = role_to_assume_arn,
    RoleSessionName = 'test',
    ExternalId = 'ABCDEFG12345'
)

creds=response['Credentials']

# open session in another account:
assumed_sess = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=creds['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=creds['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=creds['SessionToken'],
)

remote_bucket = 'remote_bucket'
s3_assumed = assumed_sess.resource('s3')
bk_assumed = s3_assumed.Bucket(remote_bucket)

for o in bk_assumed.objects.filter(Prefix="prefix/"):
    print(o.key)
    in_object = s3_assumed.Object(remote_bucket, o.key)
    content = in_object.get()['Body'].read()
    s3_local.Object('my_account_bucket', o.key).put(Body=content)
```

Error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(**TL;DR** See the very end for a way to configure permissions that is easier than using Roles!)

The easiest way to move data between buckets is to use the `copy_object()` command. This command is sent to the **destination bucket** and "pulls" information from the source bucket.

This is made slightly more complicated when multiple AWS accounts are involved because the same set of credentials requires `GetObject` permission on the source bucket *AND* `PutObject` permission on the destination bucket.

Your situation appears to be:

- `GetObject` permission has been granted on the source bucket via a Role that you can assume
- However, that role does not have `PutObject` permission on the destination bucket

It is important that provided the role is also assigned permissions to write to the destination bucket.

**To test this situation, I did the following:**

- Created `Bucket-A` in `Account-A` (the source bucket) and uploaded some test files
- Created `Bucket-B` in `Account-B` (the destination bucket)
- Created `Role-A` in `Account-A`, specifying that it can be used by `Account-B`
- Assigned this IAM policy to `Role-A`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that the role has also been given permission to write to `Bucket-B`. This might not be present in your particular situation, but it is necessary otherwise `Account-A` will not permit the role to call `Bucket-B`!

**To clarify:** When using cross-account permissions, *both accounts* need to grant permission. In this case, `Account-A` is granting `Role-A` permission to write to `Bucket-B`, but `Account-B` also has to permit the write (see Bucket Policy below).

- Created `User-B` in `Account-B` and gave permissions to call `AssumeRole` on `Role-A` in `Account-A`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AssumeRoleA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/role-a"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Created a **Bucket Policy** on `Bucket-B` allowing `Role-A` to put files into the bucket. This is important because `Account-A` does not have any access to resources in `Account-B`, but this bucket policy will allow `Role-A` to use the bucket.

```
  {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/role-a"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- Updated my credentials file to use `Role-A`:

```
[role-a]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::906972072995:role/role-a
source_profile = user-b
```

- Confirmed that I could access `Bucket-A`:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket-a --profile role-a
```

- Confirmed that I could copy objects from `Bucket-A` to `Bucket-B`:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-a/foo.txt s3://stack-bucket-b/ --profile role-a
```

This worked successfully.

**Summary**

The above process might seem rather complex but it can be easily divided between the source and destination:

- **Source:** Provided `Role-A` that can read from `Bucket-A`, also with permissions to write to `Bucket-B`
- **Destination:** Bucket policy on `Bucket-B` allowing `Role-A` to write to it

If `Account-A` is not willing to provide role permissions that can both read from `Bucket-A` and write to `Bucket-B`, then **there is another option:**

- Ask `Account-A` to **add a bucket policy** to `Bucket-A` permitting `User-B` to `GetObject`
- `User-B` can then use normal (`User-B`) permissions to read the content from `Bucket-A` *without any need for AssumeRole*
- This is, obviously, a lot easier than assuming a role

Comment: Question though, if not assumeRole is a bit complex, why use it then, in this scenario? Aside of course that it's OP's requirement.

Comment: Really appreciate for this detailed answer!